# PySide: Threading causes GUI to crash

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, pyside

I'm trying to learn the basics of threading with PySide, and so put together the below code. What I'm trying to do is launch a thread that will update a QPlainTextEdit widget using a list of string, with a delay between each string. Instead what I'm getting is a crash to desktop, and I can't understand why:

```
import sys
import time

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):

    to_log = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, txt, parent=None):
        super(Worker, self).__init__(parent)

        self.txt = txt

    def run(self):

        for i in self.txt:
            self.to_log.emit(i)
            time.sleep(1)


class TestThreadsApp(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TestThreadsApp, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.log = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.pb = QtGui.QPushButton('Go')

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.log)
        hbox.addWidget(self.pb)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()

        self.pb.clicked.connect(self.get_worker)

    def get_worker(self):
        self.proceed = False

        worker = Worker(['This is a test', 'to understand threading'])
        worker.to_log.connect(self.to_log)
        worker.start()

    def to_log(self, txt):
        self.log.appendPlainText(txt)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = TestThreadsApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I update the get_worker() method to the below, it will run, but the QPlainTextEdit widget is updated with all the strings simultaneously, where as the behavior I'm wanting is for the widget to be updated by the threaded processes as each string is emitted - not altogether after both have been emitted:

```
    def get_worker(self):
        self.proceed = False

        worker = Worker(['This is a test', 'to understand threading'])
        worker.to_log.connect(self.to_log)
        worker.start()        

        while not worker.isFinished():
            pass
```

Comment: I don't know about PySide in particular, but most UI frameworks/toolkits are not thread-safe and require any updating of the UI to occur within the main application thread.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan. It is safe to emit signals across threads in Qt (they're queued by default), so that is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to the thread, otherwise it will be garbage-collected as soon as `get_worker` returns.

So do something like this, instead:

```
    def get_worker(self):
        self.worker = Worker(['This is a test', 'to understand threading'])
        self.worker.to_log.connect(self.to_log)
        self.worker.start()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this did the trick. I'll keep this in mind re: garbage collection.